# Making A Marker Appear When Checkmark is Checked in a Different Tab

Tags: android, tabs

I have a very difficult question... so brace yourselves!  Any help or pointers would be GREATLY appreciated because this is the hardest part of my project.  **Thank you!**

[image: First Tab: A Checkable List of Grocery Items]

[image: Second Tab: A Markable Floorplan of the Grocery Store]

Here is what I want to do, and I have no idea how:

***When an item from Tab 1 is checked, a marker will be created in Tab 2.***

Comment: please elaborate as to what sort of marker you want to create?

Comment: You can use setTag() on your checkbox in tab 1 and then subsequently check getTag() in tab 2 and do whatever you want to...

Comment: @nightcrawler It can be any kind of marker.  whether that be a picture, or a unicode symbol.

Comment: hrm... thanks for that tip but could you be a little more specific?  i don't even know how I would place the marker.

Comment: from where are you going to get this picture/symbol? You just need to apply some condition and draw accordingly..

Comment: I could just draw it in paint... but my problem is that I just need to know the code that i would use.

Comment: I just need specific code if you could spare it please.